# A proper way to propagate property change event from grand (grand-grand) child to parent

Tags: java, events, properties

I'm looking for a proper way to propagate a property change event from grand child to its parent.
Let's say we have some tree structure and the root of this tree should be notified when some property changes in one of its leaves.
One way, I guess, is to add property change listener from a node to its children and re-fire, in turn, the event to predecessor.
Another way is to have the root subscribed to property change events of all its children, regardless of hierarchy.
So the question is how to do it properly? Are there any patterns for it?

Answer (score 2):

In one of my projects we developed a framework for doing that. Finally, our decision was to explicitly subscribe to properties of a nested structure and not to have something like re- firing events. This would have gotten pretty messy.

Our solution works as a map based model which consists of a tree like structure. One can register listeners anywhere in the tree. In order to make things nicer to use we wrapped it up in a proxy shell which makes the tree structure disappear behind pojos (from which the tree structure is built at construction time of the model).

Of course we looked out for frameworks that could already do what we wanted, but there were none. All existing frameworks only treated flat pojos. It was a lot of work, but now we're very pleased with it.

Comment: Btw, we use that model mainly for binding GUI elements to complex pojos.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a trade-off that depends on how frequently you modify the tree compared to how frequently you need to propagate an event.

If tree changes are frequent, I would go with passing the information back through the immediate parent up the tree. The only set-up required is a parent pointer in each node. It is also very simple.

If tree changes are relatively infrequent, and the performance of the notification process matters, it might be better to set up a direct listener relationship between the root and each leaf.